# Getting Segmentation fault at the end of FOR loop

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am getting segmentation fault at the end of FOR loop in C++ program.

This is my solution for a codeforces problem(contest has already ended).

This is my code.

```
int main()
{
    int n,x,i;
    cin>>n>>x;
    int a[n];
    int num[100010] = {0};
    long long int ans = 0;
    int temp;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cout<<n<<endl;
        cin>>temp;
        cout<<"hello"<<endl;
        a[i]=temp;
        DEBUG(temp);
        num[temp]++;
        DEBUG(i);

    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int p = (x^a[i]);
        if(p==a[i])
        {
            ans += num[a[i]]-1;
        }
        else
        {
            ans += num[p];
        }

    }

    cout<<ans/2<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the error on this input.

```
85 64800
20812 83722 93301 72100 80530 13151 28349 97347 96271 41926 5482 11948 14969 90929 13749 92741 22218 21400 31801 10359 85151 23766 12470 68911 71675 33258 99921 44095 92037 36792 17169 81178 59941 37670 12836 26619 84395 5247 40024 15103 88105 87155 94050 11878 94868 8533 71675 37910 59558 22652 61981 8920 25631 62466 3498 69017 3488 14376 88486 98762 38766 86800 6168 76705 38901 14818 51981 45686 14274 13704 67957 75111 54600 74833 67172 13908 35100 93393 2610 63043 69433 3968 80412 11293 5053
```

Comment: Please post the code, preferably a [mcve], here, not a link to the code.

Comment: Which for loop? There are two of them.

Comment: And I don't get your second loop: The condition in the if statement will only be true if x is zero, so why don't you check directly for it?

Comment: And third: How did you determine where you get the segfault?

Comment: I understood the fault. I was my fault and the answers given here are correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because some of your inputs are exceeding size of array num whose size is 100010

at line 34

int p = (x^a[i]);

this is an XOR operation which can lead p to be bigger than 100010.
For example you have an input so close to 100010 but smaller than that. When you XOR it with 64800, you can make some 0's to 1's in that input which can make it bigger than 100010.

Comment: But that still doesn't explain the the segmentation fault after the first for loop.

Comment: How do you know there is a segmentation fault in the first loop? What is the last output you get?

Comment: Sorry, I understood. It was a mistake from my side.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the operation x^a[i] throw a number bigger than 10010. Try to print the values for each iteration and see what values you have.